# Batch to move directories depending on modification date

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory whith subdirectories like this :
c:\dir1\sub (1)
c:\dir1\sub (2)
c:\dir1\sub (n)

I would like to move the latest subdirectory (sub (n)) in another path if a specific file is missing.

This is my script but I don't manage to retrieve the name of the latest subdirectory :

```
set REPdst=C:\dir2
set REPsrc=C:\dir1

IF not exist %REPdst%\index.htm (FOR /f %%f in ('dir /tw %REPsrc% ') DO (
    echo %%f
))
```

I don't know how could I retrieve only the modification date of each subdirectory in order to compare them or get index of subdirectory (the number between parentheses)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think that this kind of answers your question

http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html

```
xcopy "c:\dir1\sub (n)" "c:\dir1\sub (1)" /D /E -Y /C /Z
```

- /D will make it only replace it if its older than the the source's
- /E will make it replace folders and subfolders
- -Y will make it not prompt you for overwrite

These are not needed for you but are nice to have in there.

- /C will make it continue even if there are errors
- /Z will make it Copy files in restartable mode. If the copy is interrupted part way through,   it will restart if
  possible

Answer (score 0):

`dir` has a few helpful parameters:  `/ad` will list only directories (Attribute Directroy), `/od` will sort for date (Order Date).

Combine it: `dir /b /ad /od %REPsrc%` will list all subdirectories (oldes first)

To get the last one (the most currently modified):

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad /od %REPsrc%\sub*') do set lastdir=%%i
```

(Note: this is not neccessarily the one with the higest number)

To get the one with the highest number, sort it alphabetically (`dir /b /ad /on %REPsrc%\sub*`)

Attention: this will fail, if `n` is greater than 9.

( Note: this is not neccessarily the last modified one)

Comment: Thank you for your Help. I add "delims=\" because there is a space in the subdirectory name.